# How to load json file in elastic search

Tags: json, elasticsearch

We have master, data, client, logstash & kibana servers and how and from where I need to load this json file?

Create a new HOME LOAN index in QA environment using the file homeloan_index.json

Thanks,
Bala

Comment: this json file contains data (log) to be inserted into a elasticsearch index?

Comment: Correct. The json file contains data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logstash to do so:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/path/to/your/file.csv"
    start_position => "beginning" 
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
     separator => ","
    columns => ["id","name","age","money"] <--- insert here your columns
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     ...
  }
```

see the doc: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html